# Do atoms have an outter shell or boundary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

Do atoms have boundaries or an outer shell? If so, how do photons react to it? Also, if not, then does the atom always have the same set of electrons or do the electrons keep on changing?

What I mean to ask is, are there any boundaries which are defined? If there are, then how will it react to an incoming photon. And if not, then does a mutual exchange of electrons between atoms take place?

Answer (score 2):

An atom does not have a discrete boundary, like the surface of a baseball.  There's always some chance that an electron will be found at any distance from the center, although the probability becomes vanishingly small at distances that are not all that far from the atom.  Thus the "boundary" is kinda fuzzy, perhaps somewhat like the surface of a tennis ball.  (These are very crude analogies.)

For an atom far from any other atoms, you can safely say that the set of electrons it contains doesn't change.

If there's another atom nearby, things are complicated by one of the mysterious features of quantum mechanics.  Electrons are indistinguishable from one another in a way that has no analogy in the macroscopic world.  It is meaningless in quantum mechanics to say that two electrons have swapped places.  In fact, if we somehow manage to swap electrons, the resulting state is the *same state* as the starting state:  swapping electrons is exactly the same as doing nothing at all (but see the next paragraph).  It is fundamentally impossible to identify a particular electron and "follow it around".  This is very strange. Two nearby electrons are tangled together in a way that we can't really make sense of.

(I'm ignoring here an important detail that has no bearing on the question.  After swapping, the state of a pair of electrons is not quite the same.  The wavefunction gets multiplied by minus one, but is in all other aspects exactly the same.  What this means is another mystery of quantum mechanics, but it leads directly to the Pauli Exclusion Principle.)

So:  if two atoms get close enough to each other that the electron in one atom are "aware" of the electrons in the other, then it is impossible to tell which electron belongs to which atom.  *All* of the electrons belong to both, in the tangled sense described above.  The answer, then, is yes and no.  Yes, electrons in one atom can be said to exist in the other atom. No, because it is meaningless, after they have passed by each other, to say whether or not any electrons have swapped places.

I hope that helps with the question.  Our brains are not wired to understand the strange way nature behaves at distances very much smaller or very much larger than those we experience in everyday life.

Comment: thanx for the in sight! as for the explination upon the adsence of a boundry wall, its known that electrons revolve around the nuclious of the atom. this would mean that the nuclious is also revolving around its axes. as a result the whole atom is revolvig around its axes ?

Comment: @garyp The emphasis on entanglement is misleading. You make it sound like it happens because the *electrons* get close to one another. Chemical bonding happens because the elecrostatic potential of the nearby nuclei allow either electron to be found near the other nucleus with high probability. It's the nuclei that are important.

Comment: @user41098 Electrons don't revolve around the nucleus in the sense you're thinking. You're thinking of the Bohr model of the atom, which was not unaware of modern quantum mechanics and so is no longer accepted.

Comment: @dgh There are various models of chemical bonding: e.g. ionic, etc.   But they are all approximations.  At the bottom of it all is the fact that the *entire* electron system is subject to the constraints of exchange symmetry (swapping electrons does not result in a new state).    In quantum mechanical language, the wavefunction must be completely antisymmetric under the exchange of any two electrons. This is achieved by writing the total wavefunction as a Slater determinant, an antisymmetric combination of every electron in every possible orbital. This is the sense I meant by "tangled".

Comment: @dgh Forgot to mention this:  the nucleus has nothing to do with this "entanglement".  It applies even in the absence of electrostatic potential. "Entanglement" happens when electrons get close to each other. (Even that is not strictly needed.)   The effect of the nucleus is (among other things) to localize electrons so that the electron exchange does not become important until the nuclei are close to each other.

Comment: @garyp Of course it has nothing to do with entanglement, that was my point. You were describing bonding as the entangled state that occurs due to the overall state obeying Fermi statistics in your original answer because the electrons were close enough to be "aware" of each other. That is not correct: it's not the electron's proximity that matters but the nuclei's. You would not get bonding of any kind without the electrostatic potential. I'm not really sure why you think I need a tutorial on entanglement and Slater determinants. I know how it works; I was disagreeing with your emphasis.

Comment: @garyp To put it another way: if you had two electrons, absent two nuclei, and put them in an antisymmetric Bell state, would you call them "bonded"? Of course not. The antisymmetry of the wavefunction is a *feature* of electronic bonding, not its mechanism.

Comment: @dgh I went into more detail than necessary because we were not understanding each other.  My answer was not intended to address bonding.  I don't think I mention bonding at all.  And my interpretation of the OP was that user41098 was not addressing bonding either.  He or she does not mention bonding, but I suppose that might be what he was after, but I didn't read it that way.  So I think we're ok now:  I wasn't trying to describe bonding.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons around the nucleus are in orbitals, whose shape depends on the angular momentum eigenvalues of the energy levels which the electrons occupy. [An orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) is a probability locus of finding the bound electron at that (x,y,z).

[image: orbitals]

> The five d orbitals in ψ(x, y, z)2 form, with a combination diagram showing how they fit together to fill space around an atomic nucleus.

The image can help one understand the "shape" of atoms and when one understands that the spill over electric fields also follow this geometry, how atoms can fit or not fit in lattices to make solids or units that make liquids. Overlapping orbitals ( i.e. probabilities of the existence of the electron at that (x,y,z) will have electrons indistinguishable from each other.

In metals and semiconductors the probabilities [form bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure) in the lattice, those electrons shared by all the nuclei of the lattice.

Now the interaction of photons with the electrons  and atoms can be

1) Elastic and just be reflected without changing energy, called [Thomson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering) scattering

2)To kick them up an energy level in the atom if their energy corresponds to a gap in energy levels, and in this case the photon  will completely disappear.

3) [Compton Scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering) type, i.e some of its energy will be transferred to the electron . If the electron is bound to an atom and the energy is not comensurate with an energy gap in the atoms locations the total atom will pick up the energy as kinetic or rotations or vibrational. A lower energy photon will go away, reflected by the scatter.

[Photoelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering):  This happens with metals which have electrons in energy bands. Once the photon can overcome the band binding energy the electron is kicked out and the photon disappears.

If the photon has very high energy, a gamma ray, enough to create an [electron positron pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production), it can also happen when it hits the field of the atoms, then all the photon disappears and the energy is taken up by the three bodies, the pair and the lattice or atom.